# How to drag n drop files from QTreeWidget to windows explorer?

Tags: c++, qt

I have QTreeWidget in my application. I am adding QTreeWidgetItem into it.
The QTreeWidgetItem contains filename.
I want to drag file from QTreeWidget to windows explorer.
Thanks.

Comment: Here is a forum post which seems to be related. They discuss the other direction, though. But maybe it is a start. http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/34017-Drag-and-drop-files

Comment: Start with using search: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Drag_and_Drop_of_files